# Add entity if not existing based on some properties

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to safely add an object if a specific combination of properties is not met and update an existing one if an object is already in the database?

My current code is the following, but this is not safe for multiuser access (could result in double creation of combination as time goes by between reading from the database and writing back):

```cs
var databaseTopic = await _context.DataTopics
    .Where(dt => dt.Name == name
                 && dt.Unit == dataTopicUnit)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
if (databaseTopic == default)
{
    databaseTopic = new DataTopic()
    {
        Name = name,
        Unit = dataTopicUnit,
    };
    _context.DataTopics.Add(databaseTopic);
    
}
databaseTopic.ValueKind = valueKind;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

As you can see, I get my dataTopic based on `Name` and `Unit`, create a new one if that condition does not exist, but always update `ValueKind` no matter if it is a new `DataTopic` or an existing one.
Note: The software should be not only multiuser but also multi-service, so multiple instances of the software access the same database.

For now (dev time), I added a `SemaphoreSlim` to prevent multiple users from adding the same `DataTopic`:

```cs
await _sharedValues.CreateDataTopicGate.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

//Do all the DataTopic update and add stuff

_sharedValues.CreateDataTopicGate.Release();
```

Comment: Third party extensions can do that, if you Ok to use them. Also you can start Serializable transaction, which may block other users.

Comment: You don't need any of that code if `Name` is a primary key. The database itself will reject duplicates. A semaphore only works in a single process so it's *definitely* not useful.

Comment: If you really want an atomic INSERT you'll have to use SQL to write an `INSERT ... WHERE NOT Exists (query that returns existing row)`. This is guaranteed to avoid duplicates. You can add an `OUTPUT inserted.ID` clause to return the database-generated key, or `inserted.*` to return all inserted rows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: NOT EXISTS can't see uncommitted data, this solution can't work with concurrent transactions. You need a unique constraint for this

Comment: I didn't say it can replace the UNIQUE constraint. I said it's atomic, so there won't be a gap between checking for existence and INSERTing and no need for a transaction to cover SELECT and INSERT. I also missed the `postgresql` tag, in which case `RETURNING` is the equivalent of `OUTPUT`

Answer (score 0):

Bascially the only way to accomplish this safely, is to make your database the handler of all requests in terms of duplication.

1: Make sure you have a unique constraint on the fields that form your cardinal key, so you cannot have duplicates EVER, on said fields.

2: Read this guide:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-upsert/
adapt it to your code.

3: Profit.

I understand what you are attempting with semaphores, but really what you need, if you want to attempt to control this from a specific input component, is to implement a partition key, on your input provider. Meaning each thread you have active writing to the database, will only ever allow a certain key -> into a certain thread, making sure, you cannot land in a race condition, because a unique key, will be serially processed by the thread that uniquely processes the unique key.

This however comes with the caveat, that input can now ONLY arrive through this input provider. And that is a terrible setup.

Any other UI, device, or source, will not be able to write directly to your postgres database, as it will circumvent your partition key.

Comment: Hmmm.. but this results in having to write raw SQL, which I pretty much don't want to do as it has a high risk of refactoring issues. I think I will just add a unique constraint and catch an error on that constraint violation (I just need to teach myself how to catch specific SQL errors) by loading the value again.